# htaccess query string redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Ok so I have a url like this:

```
http://example.com/admin/test.php?action=edit&id=2
```

However I need to add in a rule to redirect this to another url with a query string like this:

```
http://example.com/admin/login.php?redirect=test.php%3Faction%3Dedit%26id%3D2
```

I added a rule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)?$ /login.php?redirect=/admin/$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [R,L]
```

And it works for the most part but there is one problem, the query string is not being escaped so it is thinking those are other $_GET variables. It looks like this:

```
http://example.com/admin/login.php?redirect=test.php%3Faction=edit&id=2
```

So the redirect is reading as test.php?action=edit. It is missing the id=2 because it is reading it as another $_GET variable instead of part of the $_GET['redirect'].

Is it possible to escape the %{QUERY_STRING} ? I have googled everything I can think of and cannot find an answer anywhere.

Comment: where are you redirecting because you might want to add something like `location("header: login.php? " . encodeuri(current url));` to your page that does the redirect. Then if redirect parameter is sent and login is ok use header decodeuri(redirect)

Comment: I dont have the option to do this. I am working in wordpress and it is coming in an email that is automatically sent. So it sends that url but I need to redirect it to login with the redirect as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you don't mind having a bunch of `&`'s at the end of your encoded URL, you can use optional captures and encode the `&` by hand. Something like:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^&]+)(?:&(.*)|)$
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)?$ /login.php?redirect=/admin/$1\%3F%1\%26%2 [L,NE,R]
```

So if you go to:

`http://example.com/admin/test.php?a=1&b=2`

you get redirected to:

`http://example.com/login.php?redirect=/admin/test.php%3Fa=1%26b=2`

However, going to:

`http://example.com/admin/test.php?a=1`

will redirect you to:

`http://example.com/login.php?redirect=/admin/test.php%3Fa=1%26`

and your php script will extract the `$_GET['redirect']` parameter as: `/admin/test.php?a=1&`. As long as you don't mind having that stray ampersand at the end.

If you have a lot of possible variables, and don't care about the ampersand, just add more `(?:&(.*)|)` to the end of the querystring condition and match them with backreferences (example, 4):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^&]+)(?:&(.*)|)(?:&(.*)|)(?:&(.*)|)$
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)?$ /login.php?redirect=/admin/$1\%3F%1\%26%2\%26%3\%26%4 [L,NE,R]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I am unsure of how many can be in there. There might even be none. I was hoping there was a bit of a cleaner solution for this.